# Create multiple columns out of one column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a text data file that is just a list of strings separated by newlines. The data is listed in groups so that all values belonging to one group are listed beneath the group title. All of the group titles with their values are listed consecutively.
When I use the following basic code to load it I end up  with something looking like this.
`df = pd.load_csv('file.txt', header = None, sep = '\n')`

```
    0
0  Group One []
1  John
2  Jacob
3  James
4  Group Two []
5  Mary
6  Molly
7  Group Three []
8  Anthony
9  Alan
```

The Group labels should actually be their own column and correspond to the values underneath them. So the format I am trying to get would look like.

```
    0           1
0  Group One    John
1  Group One    Jacob
2  Group One    James
3  Group Two    Mary
3  Group Two    Molly
4  Group Three  Anthony
5  Group Three  Alan
```

I am struggling to figure out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for match `Group` values, replace not matched to missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and forward filling them for repeating, last remove rows with same values in both columns and rename column `0`:

```
df.insert(0, 'Group', df[0].where(df[0].str.startswith('Group')).ffill())
df = df[df[0].ne(df['Group'])].rename(columns={0:'Data'})
print (df)
            Group     Data
1    Group One []     John
2    Group One []    Jacob
3    Group One []    James
5    Group Two []     Mary
6    Group Two []    Molly
8  Group Three []  Anthony
9  Group Three []     Alan
```